# Resample DataFrame in Pandas PivotTable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing 2 dates which I want to plot as index and columns in a Pandas Pivot table.

Here is the table with the data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'client_id': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 6,
  6: 7,
  7: 8,
  8: 9,
  9: 10,
  10: 11,
  11: 12,
  12: 13,
  13: 14},
 'created_date': {0: '14/05/2020',
  1: '15/05/2020',
  2: '16/05/2020',
  3: '19/05/2020',
  4: '21/05/2020',
  5: '29/05/2020',
  6: '30/05/2020',
  7: '03/06/2020',
  8: '04/06/2020',
  9: '05/06/2020',
  10: '06/06/2020',
  11: '07/06/2020',
  12: '08/06/2020',
  13: '09/06/2020'},
 'subscr_date': {0: '29/05/2020',
  1: '01/06/2020',
  2: '21/06/2020',
  3: '23/06/2020',
  4: '24/06/2020',
  5: '25/06/2020',
  6: '26/06/2020',
  7: '27/06/2020',
  8: '28/06/2019',
  9: '29/06/2020',
  10: '30/06/2020',
  11: '01/07/2022',
  12: '02/07/2020',
  13: '03/07/2021'}})
```

Using the code below I was able to create a Pandas Pivot table plotting the 2 date fields as index and column, however, the problem is that I want the data to be resampled into months data, not days like it is now.

[image]

I'm trying to use .resample('M'), but am getting an error "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'". I'm sure both of my date fields are in Datetime format.

Here is my code:

```
pd.pivot_table(data = df1, index =df1['created_date'].resample('M'), columns =df1['subscr_date'].resample('M'),  
               aggfunc='count', values ='client_id', fill_value = 0)
```

Any help highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for resample by months with convert columns to datetimes:

```
df1['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['created_date'], dayfirst=True)
df1['subscr_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['subscr_date'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df1.groupby([
    pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='created_date'),
    pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='subscr_date')
]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

print(df1)

subscr_date   2020-05-31  2020-06-30  2019-06-30  2020-07-31  2021-07-31  \
created_date                                                               
2020-05-31             1           6           0           0           0   
2020-06-30             0           3           1           1           1   

subscr_date   2022-07-31  
created_date              
2020-05-31             0  
2020-06-30             1
```

Or:

```
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='created_date'), 
                     columns=pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='subscr_date'),  
                     aggfunc='count', 
                     values='client_id',
                     fill_value=0)

print(df1)
```